# Connect jittered points by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

For this data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:50,
  Q = rnorm(50),
  A = rnorm(50,1)
)
```

I would like to connect the pairwise observations in `Q` and `A`grouped by `ID`. Here's what I have so far:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(name), y = value, fill = factor(name)))+
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, alpha = 0.5, col = "blue")+
  geom_line(aes(group = ID),
            alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]
But there are two issues:

- (i) I'm not sure the connecting lines are really between the observations with the same `ID`
- (ii) the starting points and end points of the connecting lines are not jittered, therefore they do not always coincide with the dots.

How can these issue be dealt with?

Comment: Chris, check the linked thread and a suggested different visualisation approach for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issues set `position_jitter` explicitly for both the points and the lines so that both are jittered by the same amount and for the lines switch to `geom_path`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

pj <- position_jitter(seed = 1, width = .1, height = 0)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(name), y = value, fill = factor(name))) +
  geom_point(
    alpha = 0.5, col = "blue",
    position = pj
  ) +
  geom_path(aes(group = ID),
    alpha = 0.5,
    position = pj
  )
```

[image]